# Sum of Multiples of 3 or 5 up to 1000

Tags: javascript, performance, programming-challenge

Question:

> Find the sum of multiples of 3 or 5 up to 1000

I have come up with this solution that is bit more generic than the first 1000 per se:

```
let multiplesSum = n => {

  let sum = 0

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0) {
      sum += i
    }
  }
  return sum
}
```

Instead of `pushing` everything to an array use a variable and sum the numbers as they are looping.

Comment: You should probably look at other solutions to Project Euler #1. There are lots out there.

Comment: Yeah probably right idea. After looking into some of them I found small improvment.

Comment: I find the urge to solve this problem with a one-line math formula practically irresistable. No loops required.

Answer (score 3):

#### Implementation

Your implementation is clean, robust and easy to understand. I suggest only small changes:

- Declare `multiplesSum` as **`const`** to prevent accidental rebinding / overriding later on.
- `multiplesSum(n)` should compute the sum of multiples of 3 or 5 up to **and including** n. Sum formulas are usually following this convention.
- I prefer terminating statements with semicolons instead of relying on JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion.

#### Algorithm

Your algorithm is simple and easy to understand, but comes with a linear runtime complexity of `O(n)`.

An algorithm with constant runtime complexity `O(1)` exists. Here are some pointers in case you are stuck:

- Given a positive integer n, how often do 3 or 5 fit into n? Division and `Math.floor` give the answer.
- Arithmetic sequences such as 3 + 6 + 9 + ... have simple, explicit sum formulas.
- By adding (3 + 6 + 9 + ...) + (5 + 10 + 15 + ...), you count some numbers twice, so you need to find and subtract those.